# Long Legend in Highcharts Becomes Hidden

Tags: highcharts

I have an issue with a HighCharts pie I've created. Sometimes the tooltip text overlaps with the legend, so I had to increase the legend's y property. However, this is causing parts of the legend (it's horizontal with 4 rows) to become partially hidden. I've tried adjusting the height property of the container, as well as a bunch of other properties, but the problem never goes away...

Here's how it looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXHoy.jpg

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with pagination in legend then fix the height of the legend with maxHeight.

if the legend overflows, then pagination appears automatically.

```
legend: {
maxHeight: 30,
}
```

here is a working fiddle for pagination http://jsfiddle.net/cEcRz/

hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for that tip! After some tweaking I was able to get it to display correctly, more or less...

Comment: Actually, this does not solve my problem because these graphs are being exported so the entire legend has to be visible... Any other ideas?

Comment: then it will be a tough task to accommodate all the legend items. you can do one thing, fix line height of each legend element and with also. once legend is built, try to get the legend height and do the adjustments required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pagination but in exporting add custom options to the legend like here:

http://jsfiddle.net/cEcRz/1/

```
exporting:{
        chartOptions:{
            legend:{
                layout: 'horizontal'
            }
        }
    },
```

Obviosuly you need to adapt other parameters like size etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far, but they're just workarounds that are not really helping me solve the issue. Why is the legend getting cut off in the first place? How come the frame in which the graph (and additional elements) is shows not automatically resized to fit everything correctly?